# Decide how far down bootstrap sticky navbar should be

Tags: javascript, html, css, styling

[This is the navbar we are working with](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_fixed_sticky&stacked=h).

How can you control how far up or down you want it to be/initialize?

So instead of having it start where it currently is positioned, how can I make it appear e.g. where one of the arrows is pointing?

---

[image]

Comment: how about using positive or negative margins?

Comment: @duhaime that worked! Thanks. Does anybody know if it is possible to dynamically move the sticky top navbar in relation to the container above?

Comment: For the nav there is a class `.sticky-top` you can play there with `top`

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. The navbar position only depends where it is placed inside the HTML. text - sticky navbar - text. You can arrange it the way you want. I added a new div to show you [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FU0OKX4RJ31J)

Comment: I do not recommend using negative/positive margin value. You should preferably use `position` attribute. Not sure of the use case but you can adjust the value `top` or `bottom` based on your need

Comment: @sebastianalexander if you draw a little picture of what you're going for someone here will be able to show you how to achieve it. Also, the page you link to uses `position: sticky` which is not supported in some major browsers. You may want to implement this sticky header yourself with JavaScript (it's not too hard, and folks here could help). Browser support for `position: sticky`: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky